# Forced Brace Elision in Variadic Function Call

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, aggregate-initialization

I have two PODs

```
struct A
{
   float x;
   float y;
};

struct B
{
   A a;
   int i;
}
```

and a variadic function which in-place assigns PODs using (what I think is) an aggregate

```
template<typename T, class... Args>
void remake(T* location, Args&&... args)
{
   *T = { std::forward<Args>(args)... };
}
```

The `remake` template works as I expect when used for struct A

```
remake(a_ptr, 7.0f, 6.0f)
```

but errors when used for B without brace elision: `No instance of template function 'remake' matches argument list. Argument types are: (B*, {...}, int)`

```
remake(b_ptr, {7.0f, 6.0f}, 9)
```

and works when used with B with (what I think is) brace elision

```
remake(b_ptr, 7.0f, 6.0f, 9)
```

I feel the first form of my call to remake(B*, ...) is much clearer in intention by showing explicitly where a nested struct is taking its data but is unusable in its current form. Truly I feel that the error might be a result of the subtle interactions between variadic templates and initializer lists (and a lack of understanding thereof). Or something completely different that I've missed entirely.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish in the first remake(B*, ...) form possible?
If so, what am I doing wrong that's preventing it from working as expected?

---

**Addition: Purpose**

The application in which I want this pattern is a memory-reusing homogeneous data structure that holds pre-allocated arrays for these PODs. An external object can request a POD be created, supplying the struct values, at which point the data structure finds an unused array position and fills it with these values. So remake looks something like `T* create(Args&&... args)` (The container is pointer-stable)

Comment: `{7.0f, 6.0f}` has no type, so cannot be deduced with `T&&`. You might use `remake(b_ptr, A{7.0f, 6.0f}, 9)`

Comment: There must be a reason why, in a manner of speaking, it's not possible to "kick the can down the road" when binding a braced value list to a forwarding reference.

Comment: @Jarod42 I could be totally wrong, but would your call `remake(b_ptr, A{7.0f, 6.0f}, 9)` initialize a struct A which would then be (albeit trivially) copied in the remake function when assigned to `*b_ptr`? I don't think that having the extra copy would change performance or memory characteristics very much, but it seems to go against what I thought perfect forwarding was trying to accomplish

Comment: @loaner9 what's the point of remake() ? what's the benefit over just assigning directly ? that said, if you want to avoid constructing intermidiate substructures, you could roll your own tuple-reference and use that instead, something like remake(ptr,sub{1,2},3) ... ( you could use std::tuple as well, but then you would be forced to not use them as substructures )

Comment: @loaner9 the 'perfectness' in perfect forwarding only refers to the ability of preserving r/lvalueness; it doesn't preserve the whole expression taxonomy, not to speak of non expressions ( eg. brace init lists  ).

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I've updated the question. Regarding my reasoning for this usage, I was looking for something akin to emplace_back, where the object is 'constructed' in-place in the container. I am likely to change the pattern to something like `T* create(const T& values)` which then copies the supplied struct to the unused position.